# Retrieving answer in the dictionary form from for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have data in dictionary form:

```
import numpy as np, Pysolar, datetime
my_data={'A': np.array([[-157.0, -158.0],[-29.0,30.0]]),
         'B': np.array([[-160.0, -161.0],[-31.0,32.0]]),
         'C': np.array([[-164.0, -165.0],[-33.0,34.0]])}
```

Now I have obtained my answer:

```
for x,y in my_data.iteritems():
    lons, lats = y[0], y[1]
    answers =[]
    for e,f in zip(lons,lats):
        answer = Pysolar.GetAltitude(e, f, datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        answers.append(answer)
    print answers #CORRECT ANSWER
```

BUT, how can I obtain my answers in the dictionary form assigning answers to corresponding groups(A,B,C) as in my_data?

Comment: `newdict = {}`, inside the loop `newdict[x] = answers`.

Comment: sorry, i could not make use of your code, full answer is appreciated.

Comment: This is very basic stuff, if you cannot even make sense of it then you need to through [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a new dictionary to store answers:

```
answers_dict = {}
for x, y in my_data.iteritems():
    lons, lats = y[0], y[1]
    answers = []
    for e,f in zip(lons,lats):
        answer = Pysolar.GetAltitude(e, f, datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        answers.append(answer)
    answers_dict[x] = answers
```

Comment: sorry, i could not make use of your code, full answer is appreciated.

Comment: Well if both key and value are being used inside the loop then there's nothing wrong with using `.iteritems()`. And now you're now doing two additional key look-ups.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary: you're right. I've made the change.